# Angular 5: Js not working on app.component.html

Tags: javascript, html, angular5, angular6

I want to convert the html template that I buy to angular 5. The problem is when I put the code in the app.component.html the code not working properly the css is work but the js is not working. But when I copy all the code and put directly to the index.html it working. What is possible problem with this.

When put into app.component.html
[image]

When put into index.html
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error when I got to know that once angular creates components, it renders dynamic JS. As I too was not likely to split all the JS files, Convert and place them seperately in `app.component.ts` of every component.

Here is an easy approach to achieve that.

```
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'angapp';
      constructor() { 
       this.loadScripts(); 
     }
  loadScripts() { 
  
    // This array contains all the files/CDNs 
    const dynamicScripts = [ 
        'assets/js/jquery.min.js',
       //Load all your script files here'
    ]; 
    for (let i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) { 
      const node = document.createElement('script'); 
      node.src = dynamicScripts[i]; 
      node.type = 'text/javascript'; 
      node.async = false; 
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node); 
    } } }
```

Replace your `class AppComponent` with this code in `app.component.ts` and place all your script files in `dynamicScripts` array in the same way as example is provided.

This worked for me. I hope it will solve your problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your html code in `app.component.html` and your css code in `app.component.css` and your js code in `app.component.ts`.

Comment: I put Js and css in the asset folder... and declare in angular.json style and script

Comment: Please try it by putting in to particular file that i mention.